# Python Selenium UnexpectedAlertPresentException

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am running basic CRUD tests with python and lettuce using selenium webdriver.

All of my other tests run fine, but when I click "Delete", there is a modal dialog which asks the user to confirm that they want to delete that user. The moment the popup appears, I get the exception below. I have wasted 2 hours trying to get this to work. I would imagine there is a simple fix.

```
 File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/errorhandler.py", line 164, in check_response
    raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
UnexpectedAlertPresentException: Message: u'Modal dialog present' ; Stacktrace: 
    at nsCommandProcessor.prototype.execute (file:///tmp/tmpeV2K89/extensions/fxdriver@googlecode.com/components/command_processor.js:11520:13)
```

The line in steps.py that is throwing the error is this.

```
  world.browser.find_element_by_link_text("Delete User").click()
```

And the html for that element is this.

```
<a href="/users/5910974510923776/delete" onclick="return confirm('Are you sure you want to delete this user?');">Delete User</a>
```

Comment: If its an alert use (as in java) `d.switchTo().alert().accept();` (please find equivalent binding in python). If its a modal dialog then i guess u can try finding the locator of ok.

Comment: @VivekSingh it's just `driver.switch_to_alert.accept()` or even `driver.switch_to.alert.accept()`. I've found slightly differences on both mehods so thought that's important to advice for anyone struggling around that. The same thing applies to the `driver.switch_to.window()` method.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

You need to [switch to the alert](https://www.selenium.dev/documentation/en/webdriver/js_alerts_prompts_and_confirmations/#confirm) and accept it:

```
world.browser.find_element_by_link_text("Delete User").click()
alert = world.browser.switch_to.alert
alert.accept()
```

Comment: It's not letting me get to world.browser.switch_to_alert(). I tried that, it's failing on the line before and won't go beyond it.

Comment: @andygimma so, it looks like there is an alert opened before you click on the Delete User button.

Comment: I had a typo, your answer was correct. I don't have enough reputation points to upvote you though. Thanks!

Comment: @1nflktd good point, though it should be `.switch_to.alert()`. (no need to call `switch_to` ). Thanks.

Comment: @alecxe: Should it be `.switch_to.alert()` or just `.switch_to.alert`? I'm using Python 2.7 and Selenium 2.46.0, and if I try `.switch_to.alert()`, I will get a "TypeError: 'Alert' object is not callable" exception. The source code shows that alert is decorated by @property so I think we should call it without the parentheses.

Comment: @yaobin You can't call alert as a function, wich is what `()` means. So `alert` is a object property and `alert()` is a function call, so it's "not callable". I saw both ways on another comment below this http://stackoverflow.com/q/28397370/2480481.

Comment: @yaobin It is just alert.