# Define shorter wait function

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver

**Setup**

I'm using Selenium with Python 3.x to fill out forms, and am using the common WebDriverWait function to wait for elements to load. E.g.

```
WebDriverWait(browser, 10).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CLASS_NAME, 'class-name')))
```

where `browser = webdriver.Firefox('/my/path/to/geckodriver')`

---

**Problem**

This line comes back frequently in the code; I want to define a shorter version of it to improve readability.

So far I've got,

```
wait = WebDriverWait(browser, 10)

def wait(x,y):
    if x == 'cn':
        wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CLASS_NAME,y)))
    elif x == 'xp':
        wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH,y)))
```

but the `y` doesn't carry over well and I get a,

`AttributeError: 'function' object has no attribute 'until'`.

---

How do I correctly insert `y` in the function?

Comment: For the second question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28397370/python-selenium-unexpectedalertpresentexception

Comment: It is preferred if you can post separate questions instead of combining your questions into one. That way, it helps the people answering your question and also others hunting for at least one of your questions. Break your follow-up question into a new question. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
wait = WebDriverWait(browser, 10)

def wait(x,y):
```

You should not have a variable and a function with the same name in the same scope. One will overwrite the other. When you call `wait.until` inside the `wait` function, it thinks you mean "call the `until` method belonging to the function named `wait`". But functions do not have a method named `wait`.

Choose a different name for one of them.

Comment: Changed, now receiving a different error. This time I think it is related to the `y`.

Comment: Hmm, can't say I know anything about an error like that. It's usually customary to ask a new question if you get a new error that's seemingly unrelated to the first one. Otherwise, you'll have an answer that answers the first error, but not the second; and an answer that answers the second error, but not the first, and you won't know who to award the accept to. (assuming anyone even answers the second error, which they're disincentivized to do because there's already an answer present)